# dockerpty package is taking too much time in installation

Tags: python, pip

I am downloading packages in python using pip. I am running following command.

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

In this file a package is there **dockerpty** which is taking too much time in installation. I am also command separately like as follows

```
pip install dockerpty
```

and it is not installing still. Please help. where is the issue

Comment: Please give a more detailed problem description! How long? Any output? Python and pip versions?

Comment: I am using python3 and installing this from all the pip versions but nothing I am getting

Comment: is is saying **collecting dockerpty==0.4.1** thats it.